# Read several files and write line n of each file to another file using python

Tags: python, replace, find

I have several links in a file. I want to traverse to the webpage (source) of each link, get line 443(which contains specific details as shown below) from that page and write it to another file along with the corresponding link.

**Input File:**

http://abc/app/application_144733409001

http://abc/app/application_144733409001

http://abc/app/application_144733409000

http://abc/app/application_144733409003

http://abc/app/application_144733409005

http://abc/app/application_144733409008

http://abc/app/application_144733409009

http://abc/app/application_144733409006

**Expected Output File:**

http://abc/app/application_144733409001     31098 MB-seconds, 3 vcore-seconds

http://abc/app/application_144733409001     31098 MB-seconds, 2 vcore-seconds

http://abc/app/application_144733409000     31098 MB-seconds, 3 vcore-seconds

http://abc/app/application_144733409003     31098 MB-seconds, 5 vcore-seconds

http://abc/app/application_144733409005     31798 MB-seconds, 7 vcore-seconds

http://abc/app/application_144733409008     31018 MB-seconds, 3 vcore-seconds

http://abc/app/application_144733409009     31097 MB-seconds, 3 vcore-seconds

http://abc/app/application_144733409006     31094 MB-seconds, 3 vcore-seconds

Code:

```
import sys
import urllib

Lines = [Line.strip() for Line in open ('input.txt','r').readlines()]

with open('/home/try/intermediate.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for Line in Lines:
        page = urllib.urlopen(line).read()

        #print page
```

I dont know how to proceed. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: well, that is the problem... it is internal to our network. So you will not be able to view it anyways. i just want only one line from that html page, guess it shouldn't be a problem by getting just that one line

Comment: Just count the lines as you iterate over them (use `enumerate()`) and `pass` until you have line 443.

Comment: can u show me a simple code which demonstrates??

Comment: Does it have to be line 443 or is the text unique enough so you can match on it?

Comment: the line is 443; but the text will also be unique as i have mentioned above. The text that i am trying to find will be "31098 MB-seconds, 3 vcore-seconds". Only the number varies each time.

Comment: @jeedo: is it possible to use re to get the expression that i am looking for??

Comment: @blackfury see my answer below. Depending on how you then want to use that data the `re` match groups on the relevant data (numbers) so you can save it as a csv and use the data. You might also want to consider saving this data as a [json](https://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2011/12/26/log-for-machines-in-json/) if the data is then going to be used by other machines/developers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re` to check line for the matching string
https://regex101.com/r/nU3xW1/1

```
for line in Lines:
    remoteLine = urllib.urlopen(line)
    for l in remoteLine:
        matchObj = re.match(r'(\d+) MB-seconds, (\d+) vcore-seconds', l)
        if matchObj:
            print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
```

Comment: i am not sure if urllib.urlopen(line) could read the webpage line by line. I am not getting any output

Comment: @blackfury fixed it now. you're right readline doesn't work but iterating over each line in the response does and this also means the `re` works as well